# Does Safari support javascript window.onerror?

Tags: javascript, safari, throw, onerror

I have a function attached to window.onerror

```
 window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, line) {
                window.alert('asdf');
                };";
```

This works fine in firefox, chrome and IE, but it doesn't work in safari. From some digging I read somewhere that safari does not support onerror. The post however was a few years old. Does safari currently support onerror?

If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Safari does support `window.onerror` with the function signature you posted: `function(errorMsg, url, line)`, presumably since about 2011 when [webkit added it](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8519).

However it does not **currently** support the new signature which includes the stack trace and column number: `function(errorMsg, url, line, column, errorObject)`.  This appears to be in the works, however: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55092

Firefox and Chrome already support the new syntax:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355430

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=147127

Answer (score 1):

All major browsers **now** support the syntax `function(errorMsg, url, line, column, errorObject)`. For more info see the article: https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/04/client-javascript-reporting-window-onerror