# How to log errors to XCode with JavaScriptCore?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, logging, javascriptcore

I have a project that uses JavaScriptCore to communicate between a webview and Objective C. This all works well, except I seem unable to log runtime errors to the XCode console.

I have the following:

```
- (void)createWebViewContext {
    //Find the context
    self.webViewContext = [self.webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];

    //Register JS error handler
    self.webViewContext.exceptionHandler = ^(JSContext *c, JSValue *e) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"JAVASCRIPT ERROR: %@. Stack: %@", e, [e valueForProperty:@"stack"]);
        });
    };

    //Attach logger
    id logger = ^(NSString *logMessage) {
        NSLog(@"%@", logMessage);
    };
    self.webViewContext[@"console"][@"log"]   = logger;
    self.webViewContext[@"console"][@"info"]  = logger;
    self.webViewContext[@"console"][@"error"] = logger;
    self.webViewContext[@"console"][@"err"] = logger;
    self.webViewContext[@"console"][@"warn"]  = logger;
}
```

This code DOES seem to work - if I `console.log` or `console.err` something, I get the output in XCode. The problem is that I do NOT get errors that are thrown by JavaScript (such as SyntaxErrors, TypeErrors or similar). These kinds of errors still show up in the Safari inspector, but not in XCode.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, try to check `webViewContext.exception` property, maybe this will work.

Additionally make sure that you catch all errors in window object. Like:

```
[self.webViewContext evaluateScript:@"window.onerror = function(msg) { console.err(msg)}"]
```

After that all errors should be forwarded to your console.err handler

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either. If I observe the exception property, the value only seems to change from NSNull to another NSNull :/

Comment: Oh, another thing: Try to setup window.onerror handler first and log everything to console in it. Like "[self.webViewContext evaluateScript:@"window.onerror = function(msg) { console.err(msg)}"] and then it should start cathing all the errors and forward it to console.log

Comment: perfect, that works, thank you so much! I have been looking for a method the JavaScript Interpreter uses to log errors, but I never stumbled across window.onerror. If you put that into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad that is helped. BTW be informed - as far as I remember getting javaScriptContext from UIWebView is not official API

Comment: yeah, I know, but that's not an issue for me. Another downside of this approach: It seems you cannot get a stack trace inside window.onerror

Comment: Maybe you can - check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933961/does-safari-support-javascript-window-onerror